# Where does the response come from?

Tags: javascript

If we make a request to https://reqres.in/api/users/2 (using the fetch function or the XMLHttpRequest object) and set response type to json, we will get a response.

But where in the webpage does that response come from?

Comment: What do you mean by "where does the response come from"? The server sends it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's coming from the server. Server listens to the `https://reqres.in/api/users/2` endpoint and returns that response on every request

Comment: Alright cool...